# WP_Query() 'orderby' => 'title' not working

Tags: sql-order-by, wordpress

So I have this query

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'course', // custom post type
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'   => 'title'
);

$courses = new WP_Query($args);
```

This gives me what I want, but the orderby statement is being ignored.  When I dump the `$courses->request` I get this

> 'SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type
>   = 'course' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))  ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order ASC '

It is defaulting the orderby to menu_order instead of title. What's going on here?

Comment: you need to pass both parameters `'orderby'=> 'title', 'order' => 'ASC'` ?

Comment: I've tried with and without that.  I think the default is 'ASC' anyway

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and I solved it using 'post_title' instead of 'title'.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'course', // custom post type
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'   => 'post_title' // change here
);

$courses = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

check whether you have used `parse_query` or `pre_get_posts` 
hook somewhere in the website

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'function_name' );
add_filter( 'parse_query',  'function_name' );
```

Comment: There are a few instances of those in an events calendar plugin the client is using.  However if I disable that, it still doesn't work.

Comment: It could be `add_filter('posts_orderby', 'function_name');` as well. Can you look for it, @JohnHalsey?